# My SQL Query works in PHPMyAdmin but not in my PHP code, can anyone tell why?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two PHP files talking to each other. One invokes a function in another to access the database and fetch data.

Here is the function which is **invoking** the other :

```
$app->post('/responsiveCalender', function() use ($app) {

verifyRequiredParams(array('restaurant_id'));

$restaurant_id      = $app->request()->post('restaurant_id'); 

$db      = new DbHandler();
$response = array();

$dish_details = $db->getRestaurantDishDetails($restaurant_id);  

if($dish_details != null)
{
    foreach($dish_details as $key)
    {
        $available_dates = $db->getAvailableDates($dish_details);
    }
    $response = $available_dates;
}
else {
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['code'] = 102;
}

echoRespnse(200, $response);
});
```

This code returns `error = 'true'` and `code = '102'` if `$dish_details = null`.

This is the method being **invoked** :

```
public function getRestaurantDishDetails($restaurant_id)
{
        /* $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, "SELECT 'dish_id' FROM       restaurant_dish WHERE restaurant_id = '$restaurant_id'") or die(mysqli_error($this->conn)); */

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT 'avail_by_date' FROM `restaurant_dish` WHERE 'restaurant_id' = ? ");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $restaurant_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($result);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
    return $result;
}
```

I'm passing `$restaurant_id = 22` in the REST client, which gives me an `avail_by_date` in the **PHPMyAdmin code**. But it returns me an `error='true'` in my **REST client**.

Can anyone tell me why this code is returning an empty array, when the SQL statements should not be empty?

EDIT : Added a  `$result = array();`  above all the code.

EDIT2 : Current query is : ``` SELECT ``avail_by_date`` FROM ``restaurant_dish`` WHERE ``restaurant_id`` = 22 ```

Its just one pair of ``, don't worry.

Comment: Try to wrap the $stmt->bind_param("i", $restaurant_id) in an IF structure to make sure the binding worked. You may want to get the bool value for all methods to narrow down what may be happening.

Comment: @RyanNerd Let me give this a shot.

Comment: @RyanNerd Can you give me a snippet? I'm kinda confused on what to do.

Comment: See my answer below. I think bind_result() as well as fetch() and close() return true if they worked. The $stmt->error should have error details if the function failed.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

if ($stmt->bind_param("i", $restaurant_id) === false)
   {
     return array($stmt->error);
   }
if ($stmt->execute() === false)
   {
    return array($stmt->error);
   }
```

Comment: Its not echoing anything back. Its still showing me a error = 'true'.

Comment: I've retooled the code so that it now returns an array containing a string if there was an error. In your code that invokes the function you should check if the array contains a string or a date type.

Comment: Added this code. 

        `$temp = array();
 
 $temp = gettype($dish_details);
 
 echoRespnse($temp);  `


Code is compiling.

EDIT : Its returning a NULL array. gettype is giving a NULL result.

Comment: One other thing you can try in the method being invoked is instead of return array($stmt->error) as I suggested, instead throw an error:   throw new \Exception("Database error: $stmt->errno - $stmt->error");

Comment: Wouldn't I need to catch that exception somewhere?